# Four-part formula syntax in R

Tags: r, package, regression, linear-regression

I am using the `lfe` package for high dimenaional fixed effects in `R`. I am having trouble when trying to run with no covariates. That is, only with fixed effects. My code is:

```
library(lfe)
data=read.csv("path_to//my_data.csv")

y <- cbind(col1)
x <- cbind(col2)

est <- felm(y ~ 0|x, data)
```

However, the last line gives the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Notice that I am calling it with proper syntax, according to the four-part formula formatting, as can be seen in page 20 of the [`documentation`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122050305/https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf), where it says:

> The formula specification is a response variable followed by a four part formula. The first part
> consists of ordinary covariates, the second part consists of factors to be projected out. The third
> part is an IV-specification. The fourth part is a cluster specification for the standard errors. I.e.
> something like `y ~ x1 + x2 | f1 + f2 | (Q|W ~ x3+x4) | clu1 + clu2` where `y` is the
> response, `x1,x2` are ordinary covariates, `f1,f2` are factors to be projected out, `Q` and `W` are covariates
> which are instrumented by `x3` and `x4`, and `clu1,clu2` are factors to be used for computing cluster
> robust standard errors. Parts that are not used should be specified as `0`, except if it’s at the end of the
> formula, where they can be omitted.

Comment: One unrelated point, using `attach` is a bad idea. I'm nearly certain that `felm` has a `data` argument. Use this instead. You should be able to write this as `est <- felm(col1 ~ 0 | col2, data=data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a syntax problem, as suggested by @lmo. If I do:

```
est <- felm(col1 ~ 0|col1data)
```

then there is no error and it works